# How to customize product URL?

Tags: magento

How to customize the product URL to add certain attribute such as EAN on URL part? For example I want make url like `[domain]/cars/[sku]/tata-suv.html

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I am gonna be short and quick here.

1) You have to customize `Mage_Catalog_Model_Url::getProductRequestPath`. You have add following statements.

```
$sku = $product->getSku();
$requestPath = 'cars/' . $sku . "/" . $requestPath;
```

May be Add this just before following line:

```
if (strlen($requestPath) > self::MAX_REQUEST_PATH_LENGTH + self::ALLOWED_REQUEST_PATH_OVERFLOW) {
    $requestPath = substr($requestPath, 0, self::MAX_REQUEST_PATH_LENGTH);
}
```

2) Customize the collection `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Url::_getProducts` add sku in select field list:

```
$select = $adapter->select()
        ->useStraightJoin(true)
        ->from(array('e' => $this->getTable('catalog/product')), array('entity_id', 'sku'))
        ->join(
            array('w' => $this->getTable('catalog/product_website')),
            'e.entity_id = w.product_id AND w.website_id = :website_id',
            array()
        )
        ->where('e.entity_id > :entity_id')
        ->order('e.entity_id')
        ->limit($this->_productLimit);
```

Notice, `sku` in `array('entity_id', 'sku')`