# Add SKU to end of Magento URL

Tags: magento, url

I have searched for days trying to find a way of doing this but cannot find an answer, hopefully someone here can help me.

Essentially we want to insert the SKU into the product page url

Example
SKU =   ST500DM002

So
domain.co.uk/seagate-barracuda-500gb-sata3.html

Would become
domain.co.uk/seagate-barracuda-500gb-sata3-ST500DM002.html

I had a look at this [How to customize product URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23987445/how-to-customize-product-url)

It kind of works but it creates a path like this http://www.domain. co.uk/catalog/product/ST500DM002/seagate-barracuda-500gb-sata3.html rather than add it onto the end

Also we have a lot of SKUs with # in them which causes problems and throws 404
Is there a way to programmatically add the SKU and strip out #

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Copy the code and paste it to the file "script.php" and move it to magento root folder and try to run it in browser by using the following url,
http://localhost.com/script.php

```
<?php
    require 'app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app();
    $amount = 0;
    $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $products = $model->getCollection();
    foreach ($products as $product) {
    $model->load($product->getId());
    $urlkey = $product->getUrlKey();  
    $sku = $product->getSku();
    $product->setUrlKey($urlkey."/".$sku)->save();
    set_time_limit();
    $amount++;
}
```

When you run the file, All the urls will be rewritten with the new url keys. 
You can find updated keys everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for info, will this change future URls, we import 1000s of products everyday and would need something that automatically changes them?

Comment: Let me tell u  idea. Give smetime.

Comment: @shane8020  How do you import products? using default import process or using some extension?

Comment: We use a custom extension to import products, it imports sku, price, images, descriptions etc. it performs a full import replacing or updating all existing information. I tried the the solution I linked to and it works except for the issues mentioned, could this solution be modified to do what I need?

Comment: Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Create observer to catch event catalog_product_save_after_handler

```
$product = $observer->getProduct();
$urlkey = $product->getUrlKey();
$sku = $product->getSku();                
if(substr($urlkey, strlen($sku) * (-1)) != $sku){
    $product->setUrlKey($urlkey."/".$sku)->save();                
}
```